# laravel 4.2 regenrating session on redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, laravel-4

i have a laravel version 4.2 which working fine in php 5.4,5.5 on login section . but when i switched to 5.6.23  it started genrate multiple session. i am getting success on from auth::attempt but just after redirect to dashboard everything gone, nothing in season . i have check session folder the session exist their but, 2-3 more session generated after redirection.

```
<?php
```

return array(

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|sessions
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => array(2, 100),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|myapp_session
*/

'cookie' => 'myapp_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => false,
```

);

my form action handler

```
  public function verify()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    if (!User::count()) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->password = $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login');
    } else {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password))) {

            Session::put('username', $username);
            if (Session::has('pre_admin_login_url')) {
                $url = Session::get('pre_admin_login_url');
                Session::forget('pre_admin_login_url');
                return Redirect::to($url);
            } else {

                return Redirect::to('/admin/dashboard')->with('notify','installation Notification');
            }
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/login?error=1');
        }
    }

}
```

i try to change all this value, already check there no space or new line in any starting tag of  php .. please help i don't want to upgrade whole project version.. thanks

Comment: Finally i solved it at my own.. after 16 hours of RND (bocz i am newbee to laraval). i found that you have to stop making new id for sessoion in this function ..protected function generateSessionId()
 {
  //return sha1(uniqid('', true).str_random(25).microtime(true));
  return md5('sunny_fixed_issue');
 }       path:   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Store.php....... at least it solved my prob. hope it help you too

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem long ago. After searching couple of days I found There is a problem with laravel  generateSessionId function **when it comes to php 5.6.23** . you can find this method here crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php.. line :171

```
protected function generateSessionId()
    {
//      return sha1(uniqid('', true).str_random(25).microtime(true));
            return md5('Getpikk');
    }
```

this is what i did to solve my problem . I hope it helps you too..

Answer (score -1):

I had  the same problem and I solved it removing spaces and lines before  at end of these files too.